# ReactJS: element isn't updated when state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that is set up like so:

```
export default class FormDialog extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {allowedToDelete: false};
  }
  onChange(event) {

    if (event.target.value.match(this.targetName)) {
      console.log("It's a match!");
      this.state = {allowedToDelete: true};
      console.log(this.state); 
    } else {
      this.state = {allowedToDelete: false};
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { profile, deleteUser, handleDialogClose, ...other } = this.props;
    this.targetName = `${profile.firstName} ${profile.lastName}`;
    console.log({...other})

    return (
      <Dialog {...other}>
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Delete this user?</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            allowedToDelete: {String(this.state.allowedToDelete)}
          </DialogContentText>
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            id="name"
            label="User's Full Name"
            type="text"
            fullWidth
            onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button variant="outlined" onClick={this.handleDialogClose} color="primary">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button variant="outlined" onClick={this.deleteUser} disabled={!this.state.allowedToDelete} color="primary">
            Delete User! 
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    );
  }
}
```

(I'm using material-ui's form dialog component here).

As above, a user is prompted to type the full name of the profile they want to delete; if they match the name, then the "Delete User!" button should become un-disabled.

My `onChange()` event is working, in that when I type the correct name I see `It's a match!` in my console and the log of `this.state` shows that `this.state.allowedToDelete === true`.

However, my render function's `allowedToDelete: {String(this.state.allowedToDelete)}` as well as my button's `disabled={!this.state.allowedToDelete}` both remain `false`.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm new to React to my understanding of state may be confused, but I've tried doing this with variables attached directly to `this` instead of state and that doesn't work either...

Comment: React examples and docs clearly outline how to change state. Use setState.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `setState`. You can read about it [in the react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). This is what tells the react components to trigger the lifecycle to show the new state.

```
this.setState({allowedToDelete: false});
```

Comment: Ah, didn't know this, I'm a fool. Thanks!